# How to turn on and off data in a formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a calculator that calculates total amount of space needed to store inventory. I already know the quantity per container and the size of the containers. I won't always have the need to store the same inventory items though. What I would like to do is make a sheet so that I can click on and off the items I want to input the total number of items I need in order to calculate the total space I need. For instance I want to make a chocolate cake, it will take eggs, flour, milk, sugar, and chocolate to make. So I would click on those materials and input I want to make 10 cakes and it would calculate how much space it would take to store those ingredients. Next though I want to make 10 plain cakes so I could click off the chocolate and calculate how much space it would take to store the ingredients for 10 plain cakes. I already have it making calculations needed but its for all inventory and I have to manually take out the cells in the formula I don't want calulate

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likey to be closed.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: sounds like you need to use some form of `if` statement

Comment: You can try to provide the picture about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution on my own. I added an additional column to read 0 or 1. 1 if the inventory is needed 0 if not. Then in my space requirement column I added an IF statement (IF(A1=1,(calulate space need),0)). By doing this I can just manualy add 0,1 to show whats needed per project and it will calculate as needed then sum up the parts in a separate calculation